# Как обновлять статусы MenuItem'ов?

Tags: wpf

Хотелось бы узнать как лучше реализовать следующую фичу. Допустим, некое приложение имеет меню. При создании приложения это меню создается. Каждый MenuItem содержит определенную команду. При выполнении какой-нибудь команды, некоторые MenuItem'ы должны дизаблиться. И наоборот, при выполнении другой команды, быть доступными на выполнение. Как лучше реализовать такое поведение? Вижу несколько вариантов:

1. Выполнить связку. То есть сделать свойство IsEnabled зависимым. Каждый раз, когда меняется target свойство, происходит изменение зависимого свойства (лично я так понимаю механизм связки)
2. Создать событие MenuItemAccessChanged, в обработке которого принудительно обновлять все menu item'ы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше всего это реализовывать через команды.

Когда вы привязываете `MenuItem`'ы к команде, его состояние enabled/disabled автоматически привязывается к `CanExecute` вашей команды.

Таким образом, вы можете на время выполнения одной команды отключать остальные, а потом включать назад, просто выставляя это свойство у вашей реализации `ICommand`.

Comment: Да, это отличный подход, спасибо.

Comment: @LmTinyToon: Пожалуйста!